# Run multiple React Apps on single domain using Nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx

Can anyone recommend a best practice nginx config to run multiple React apps on a single domain? The apps will be served out of different root directories.

So app1 and app2 run on www.domain.com and get served as:

```
www.domain.com/app1
www.domain.com/app2
```

App1 serves from
    /tmp1/app1

App2 serves from
    /tmp2/app2

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an expert with react apps but here's few simple ways to do this.

In both of these cases make sure that your application understands that it's served from a subfolder so you need to prefix all of your requests with `/app1/` or `/app2/`.

### Option 1:

This example is just simplest possible config which serves the static files.

```
server {
  server_name www.domain.com;

  # Serve files for different applications from different paths

  # Matched location will automatically search files under /tmp1
  # For example request "GET /app1/index.html" returns file /tmp1/app1/index.html
  location /app1 {
    root /tmp1;
  }

  location /app2 {
    root /tmp2;
  }
}
```

You just need to make sure that the folder name matches the subfolder name in your request.

### Option 2:

Other way to do this is to match the request after the subfolder with `regex` and use `try_files`. This way your root folder path can be anything.

```
# Serve files from subfolders using regex
# This comes with additional bonus of matching all requests to the index.html which is usually prefered for react apps
server {
  server_name www.domain.com;

  # Now your root can be anywhere and it doesn't need to contain folder 'app1'
  location /app1/(.*) {
    root /tmp1/app1;
    try_files $1 index.html;
  }

  location /app2/(.*) {
    root /tmp2/app2;
    try_files $1 index.html;
  }
}
```

Comment: do we need to define root inside `server {` as well?

Comment: Neither option 1 or 2 works with a deployed react app. I get `[error] 22#22: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/app1" failed (2: No such file or directory)` `try_files` does not work with `root`.

Comment: @JeffreyTillwick You probably already solved this but that error message looks like that you don't have any files in the path "/etc/nginx/html/app1". Can you double check that react files are actually in that folder?

Answer (score -2):

Place

`rewrite ^/app1/(.*)$ /$1 break;`

Under

`location /app1/ {`

Comment: Please, provide the explanation.