# Multiple React Apps with NGINX

Tags: reactjs, nginx, create-react-app

I am trying to host 2 react apps on an NGINX server. My configuration is currently as follows:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.domain.net;

location / {
  root /var/www/portfolio_site/code/client/build;
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}

location /json/ {
    root /var/www/json-converter-yay/build;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /json.html;
}
```

}

I have tried both solutions mentioned at this post: [Run multiple React Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45265570/run-multiple-react-apps-on-single-domain-using-nginx)

Which gives me a 404 error if I navigate to the /json, and a message informing me that NGINX has been set up if I navigate to root. Currently, the root location works just fine, but navigating to domain.com/json renders the index page. I have cleared my cache and tested on multiple computers, as well as verifying that I have my paths configured correctly.

Comment: You can serve your server on different ports and make nginx listen to different reacts apps on different ports. Thats how i do it.

Comment: Can you share your configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Without the knowledge of how your files are organized on disc it's hard to say for sure, but this may happen because `root` directive includes the location when looking for files. I. e. hitting `example.com/json/` will make nginx look for files in `/var/www/json-converter-yay/build/json/`.

If this is the case for you, and `/json/` ending is not desirable, `alias` directive instead of `root` can help you. See this excellent SO answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10647080/4166517. Also, see the comment there: "The trailing slash on the alias path is essential!"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my config file @alex-wright :

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  #location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
  #}
  location / {
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3003;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    send_timeout 600;
  }
}
```